# Why can I build from command line, but not Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, gnu-make

I'm currently working on a project that uses GNU Make to build. When I attempt to build from Visual Studio using NMake, the build fails and all information I get is the path to where the compiled file would be "error 255" (which intense Googling has revealed nothing about). However, when I open a command prompt window and input the exact same command, it builds just fine. What causes this, and is there a way to fix it?

Comment: It sounds it like it must be caused by differing environment variables between your command prompt and VS.

Comment: You can build with nmake manually or with GNU make manually? Because they aren't the same thing.